# Logging in using libCurl

Tags: lua, libcurl

I was trying to log in using LibCurl. Actually I am using LuaCurl the binding of libCurl in Lua. I am referring to this web page: http://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078

I tried this:

```
> require("libcurl")
> c=curl.new()
> c:setopt(curl.OPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0")
> c:setopt(curl.OPT_AUTOREFERER,true)
> c:setopt(curl.OPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true)
> c:setopt(curl.OPT_COOKIEFILE,"")
> c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL,"https://www.chase.com")
> res=c:perform()
```

But after this last operation the program is stuck as if waiting for something. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program and it seems to work fine. What I get is the content of the given site pumped to `stdout`. It seems you are just having networking issues...

If you want to capture the whole output as a string and process it later, you have to provide a callback using `OPT_WRITEFUNCTION` which will be called with more data which you can save. Here is a simplified version of how I implemented the `GET` method in my simple web-mining toolbox [WDM](https://github.com/mkottman/wdm/blob/master/wdm.lua#L243).

```
local c = curl.new()
... 
function get(url)
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL,url)
    local t = {} -- output will be stored here
    c:setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function (a, b)
        local s
        -- luacurl and Lua-cURL friendly way
        if type(a) == "string" then s = a else s = b end
        table.insert(t, s) -- store this piece of data
        return #s
    end)
    assert(c:perform())
    return table.concat(t) -- return the whole content
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I seem to be getting the http sites fine but https doesn't seem to work. For chase.com it just keeps waiting. For discover.com it outputs nothing and the return value is also nil. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: When you connect to a site with a self-signed certificate, you should get `"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates"` as a second return value: `local ok, err = c:perform()`. Try wrapping it in an assert: `res = assert(c:perform())`. When you get an error with incorrect certificate, try setting `c:setopt(curl.OPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`.